# Handle Subclass Callbacks in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, http, callback, subclass

My question is more conceptional than code-based.  I'm looking for the best way to handle asynchronous program flows using subclasses.

Imagine that you build a REST service and you outsource the whole communication code to a class called `REST`. I want to read all categories from my database and display them in my GUI. If we were synchronous, we could just write:

```
cats = REST.GetCategories();
UpdateMyGUI(cats);
```

But as we are asynchronous, `UpdateMyGUI(cats)` would be called, before `REST.GetCategories()` returns. So we end up with an endless list of subclass function calls: something like

```
REST.GetCategories() => $http() = (WaitingforHTTPResponse) => GetResult() => AnalyseResult() => ?
```

My question: **What's the best way to make the program call `UpdateMyCategories()` once I get a result from the server?**

As `UpdateMyCategories()` is part of the main program, it's at least messy coding to call this function directly (and hard-coded) inside the `REST` class. My first idea was to create an object like

```
var _data = { func: UpdateMyCategories, params: [] };
```

and to enlarge all functions inside the `REST` class with a parameter to forward the `_data` object to the very last function, where it could be called. I could also forward an event name instead of a function pointer.

But is there no better way to do this? What's the real JavaScript way here?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Why aren't promises the solution here?

Comment: Thank you, that's the "better way", I was looking for :) Didn't know promises. Here are some information on that; quite good explanation http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/?redirect_from_locale=de